# Spring autowiring dillema when using injection by both interface and implementation

Tags: java, spring

Consider we have interface CountryService, which has one implementation: CountryServiceImpl which is annotated with @Service

We also have ITTest for CountryImpl.

The problem:

Frequently when running tests we want to explicitly show what we are testing so we are autowiring by implementation, so we create ITTest:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class, loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)
@ActiveProfiles(ProfileConstants.SPRING_PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT)
public class CountryServiceITTest {

    @Autowired
    CountryServiceImpl countryServiceImpl;

    @Test
    public void test() {
     countryServiceImpl.getAllCountriesTranslationsInLanguage("en");
    }
```

So far so good. We run our test and it is green. Now lets make life little more fun.

We add a `CountryResource` with `CountryResourceImpl` @RestController which @Autowire (s) CountryService.

We run our test again and suddenly we receive error message causing maddness:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'countryResourceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com....service.CountryService com....rest.CountryResourceImpl.countryService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com....service.CountryService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

This behavior reveals an interesting thing:

Once we autowire by interface, we can't autowire by direct implementation somewhere else. This works vice versa(if we autowire by impl the interface injection will fail).

Please explain why is this happening?

Comment: Why are you autowiring the implementation, rather than the interface? I'd expect to see an exclude-filter for the impl packages and mock objects in the test package.

Comment: Because I want to explicitly say in the code that I am testing this particular implementation. I have many implementations for different enviornments, otherwise for people to infer what I am testing, they will have to lookup the profile annotations.

Comment: Is CountryServiceImpl is being wraped in a proxy object? Could it be that the proxy object is implementing the interface but is not an instance of the implementing class?

Comment: Something is definitely off ! In other project I can autowire in the simillar test by interface and implementation the same object. Can't find anything different... Don't even know which one is correct behavior.

Comment: @Aubergine is right. It doesn't matter what type of object is Autowired (whether interface or the implementation). To troubleshoot further, I think you should create a standalone application to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I think your test approach is wrong. You want a unit test rather than an integration test. For the integration test you want to use the interface and let spring do the wiring. For the unit test you want to use no spring and just instantiate the service implementation yourself (and maybe mock some dependencies). So I would say that your test is off.

Comment: So we investigated the mystery, of course it is AOP, namely the service was annotated as Transactional which triggers proxying as @Robert says. The other object was not proxied so you could do both.

Comment: Do you have @EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true) somewhere over your configuration classes? The javadoc for that annotation states, that it "enables CGLIB-style 'subclass' proxies as opposed to the default interface-based JDK proxy approach".